# Query synonyms table at oracle via Java-jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ora-00942

I am trying to query Oracle `synonyms` table via my Java `jdbc` and getting-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Is there a different way to query this kind of table then - [My query example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm)
The rest of my querys work's fine on 'normal' tables.
Thank you.

Comment: please show us the query and confirm that the user you are connecting with has privileges to select on that table.  try connecting with sql plus and run the same query

Comment: Which user are you supplying as dbuser in the connection?

Comment: Sql+?  It is Oracle DB, I am using the scheme name as user name.

Comment: @JSapkota - The user name is the same as the scheme name. why?

Comment: @Itsik: Because does that user have select privilege on that synonym? Or that user owns the synonym?

Comment: @JSapkota The user as select privilege, but the problem is that the I get - table or view does not exist, is this the same error code for no  privilege ?